# JIRA - Rest API Sending Email Notifications to Specific Emails

Tags: python, rest, email, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm currently working with the JIRA Rest API and I'm trying to send an email notification to specific email addresses that are not registered as users. Currently I'm only able to send email notifications to users. Does anyone know if it's possible to send email notifications through jira api to specified email addresses instead of users.

Here is my current code for doing this. Note that it specifies users instead of email addresses:

```
import requests

url = "https://jiraserver.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/{issue_key}/notify"

notify_data = {
        "subject": "Test Issue Name",
        "textBody": "Test issue body.",
        "htmlBody": "Test issue <strong>html<strong>",
        "to": {
            "users": [ #replace with email addresses
                {
                    "name": "JIRA_user"}]
        },

    }

requests.post(url,auth=('jira_username','jira_password'), json=notify_data)
```

Here is the rest api documentation I was looking at: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-notify.

Does anyone know if Jira's API supports this? If not is there a good workaround?

Comment: I would say that it's not supported, i.e. you can't send notification to arbitrary emails. Though, it's possible to create fake user and configure email as you like. I think it should be possible to input multiple email addresses using semicolon. Then you can use notification API with your user to send messages to the given emails.

Comment: As far as a good workaround -- no. It looks like Atlassian has no interest in supporting such a stupid-simple feature. https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-3160